# Alter the "Complete action using" dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, intentfilter

I am writing an app to send an MMS with an image file. I wrote the following code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String sendfilepath = "file://" + sendfile.toString() + ".jpg";
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(sendfilepath)) ;
        i.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivityForResult(i, 1) ;
```

However, the app shows The "Complete action using" dialog to choose from many things like Bluetooth, Email, facebook, Gmail, Handcent SMS, Messaging, play on Device.

I would like to show the dialog with only the things that are related to sending SMS or MMS like Messaging and Handcent SMS. I do not want to show all the other apps. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a specific phone number that you are trying to let the user send a message to, use `ACTION_SENDTO` with a `smsto:` `Uri` for the phone number that you want to send the message to. That definitely works for SMS; I presume it will work for MMS, but I have not tried that.

Otherwise, what you want is not a good idea. Your users may wish to share their data via any number of mechanisms, some of which will not be MMS apps. [Please let the *users* choose how to share *their* data](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html).